# dropdown menu not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down menus which both have 'name'=list1. I also have 2 radio buttons 'yes' or 'no'. When select no all dropdown menus should be hidden, when selected 'yes' all drop down menus should show however at the minute only one is showing when clicked yes none showing when clicked no.

JavaScript code to hide:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(targetElement,toggleElementClass){
  var els,
      i;
  if (targetElement.checked) {
    els = document.getElementsByClassName(toggleElementClass);
    for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
       els[i].style.visibility = "visible";
       els[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
function HideDiv(targetElement,toggleElementClass){
  var els,
      i;
  if (targetElement.checked) {
    els = document.getElementsByClassName(toggleElementClass);
    for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
       els[i].style.visibility = "visible";
       els[i].style.display = "block";
    }

// and similar for hideDiv()
</script>
```

code for 1st dropdwon:

```
    <div style="display: none;" class="list1" >
<select name="colour">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>red</option>
    <option>orange</option>
    <option>blue</option>
</select>
```

code for 2nd drop down:

```
    <div id="list2" style="display: none;" class="list2" >
<select name="shade">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>dark</option>
    <option>light</option>
</select>
</div>
```

only the 1st is displaying on webpage. does anyone know why?

Comment: where is the `HTML` for `id=radio1` ?

Comment: where are items like radio1 and radio2 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, i.e., no two elements should have the same id. If you have two (or more) elements with the same id the [`document.getElementById()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) will likely return the first - behaviour may vary from browser to browser but in any case it will definitely only return either one element or null.

If you want to apply the same change to multiple similar elements you could try giving those elements the same class and select them with the [`.getElementsByClassName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
<div class="list1"></div>
<div class="list1"></div>

<script>
function showDiv(targetElement,toggleElementClass){
  var els,
      i;
  if (targetElement.checked) {
    els = document.getElementsByClassName(toggleElementClass);
    for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
       els[i].style.visibility = "visible";
       els[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

// and similar for hideDiv()
</script>
```

Another method you might like to look into is [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Notice that `.getElementById()` is "element", singular, while the other two methods I mentioned get "elements", plural...

**EDIT:** My apologies, I don't think IE supported `.getElementsByClassName()` until version 9. If you are using IE8 you can substitute the following line in the above function:

```
els = document.querySelectorAll("div." + toggleElementClass);
```

and the rest should work as is. Here is a demo that I've tested as working in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/CVS2F/1/

Alternatively for even older IE version support where you can't use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) you could just use `.getElementsByTagName("div")` and then within the loop test each returned element to see if it has the class you care about. Here's an updated demo that works that way: http://jsfiddle.net/CVS2F/2/

Comment: I have edited my post. could i use the revised code or would it be better to use yours?

Comment: I have re-edited my post to your recommendations. However it still does not work. Nothing will show if it is on 'yes' or 'no'. please can you have a look thanks

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that IE doesn't have `.getElementsByClassName()` until version 9, so although you don't mention which browser you're using perhaps that's what's going wrong for you and in any case you most likely do need to support older versions. So I've updated my answer with two other options. (Just as an aside: I wouldn't recommend a for..in loop to access an array-like object, use a conventional for statement as shown in my answer. for..in will work - except when it doesn't; in some cases it'll result in hard-to-find bugs.)

Comment: Take a look at the jsfiddle link at the bottom of my answer - you can quickly test from there whether it works in your browser, and see the code there. I would expect that to work in IE at least as far back as version 5.5, and in other browsers. By the way, like a lot of people I tend to get around these browser compatibility issues by using a JS library that does it for me. I use jQuery, but there are other options...

Comment: thanks for the update. I need it to work in all broswers. older and newer versions and not just mine as i am going to host it an others can access from other computers. could you possibly help me with jquery if this is the easiest option??

Comment: great it all works. Should this code work in all browsers now?

what about  Umesh code below. does it do the same as yours/ just as good?

Comment: Umesh's code is fine. Basically it is the same `.getElementsByClassName()` solution as my original answer except that it includes an implementation of that method that will add the method for browsers that don't have it built-in (though it should add it inside an `if` test so it doesn't do it when the method already exists). If you look at how the method was implemented you'll see it uses `.getElementsByTagName()` anyway, a bit like the demo I did...

Comment: cool tahnks again. would you know about this query as posted above

 
the code is pastebin.com/1XgfTuYd. I also have a submit button link to mysql which submits the data. but when i click 'no' there is no value submitted as dropdowns are hidden so an error pops up. is there away around this to ignore hidden dropdowns?

Comment: I am now using jquery as you suggested and it is all working. Can you please see my question about validating. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153060/dropdown-validation-error-if-no-value-is-selected-jquery

Answer (score 0):

To clear all your confusion, I came up with working test HTML below. Save the code as HTML and test  if is it give what you wanted?

What you need to do is change 'id' to 'class', so you can select multiple elements into an array. Iterate that array and apply the style.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=registerEventHandlers;
document.getElementsByClassName = function (cn) { 
        var rx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + cn+ "(?:$|\\s)");
        var allT = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), allCN = [], ac="", i = 0, a;
            while (a = allT[i=i+1]) {
              ac=a.className;
              if ( ac && ac.indexOf(cn) !==-1) {
                if(ac===cn){ allCN[allCN.length] = a; continue;   }
                rx.test(ac) ? (allCN[allCN.length] = a) : 0;
              }
            }
        return allCN;
    }
 function registerEventHandlers()             
{
        document.getElementById("radio1").onclick = function(){                 
                hideDiv(this,"list1")             
         };             
         document.getElementById("radio2").onclick = function(){                 
                    showDiv(this,"list1")                    
         };                           
 }              

 function showDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){ 
         var showAll=document.getElementsByClassName(toggleElementId);
         for(i in showAll){
            showAll[i].style.visibility="visible";
            showAll[i].style.display="block";
         }                         
 }            
 function hideDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){                
         var hideAll=document.getElementsByClassName(toggleElementId);
         for(i in hideAll){
            hideAll[i].style.visibility="hidden";
            hideAll[i].style.display="none";
         }                            
 } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
Yes:<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="yesNo" value="yes" />
No:<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="yesNo" value="no"/>
<div class="list1" style="display: none;" >
        <select name="colour">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option>red</option>
            <option>orange</option>
            <option>blue</option>
        </select>
</div>
  <div class="list1" style="display: none;" >
<select name="shade">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>dark</option>
    <option>light</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. I don't use IE doesn't mean all others should not use.. Whatever you create HAS TO work in ALL BROWSER... 2. why not working in IE is not a question for me... you should check why it is not working as  you have coded it...

Comment: Yes Sir !! I will let you know as soon as I get it :)

Comment: @FahimParkar, +1 to you. I saw getElementsByClassName was not working in IE. Now, I have made IE to accept this code by defining it !!

Comment: You should add an if test so that you don't redefine `getElementsByClassName()` if it already exists...

Comment: @nnnnnn, Yes. It is also one way to prevent such errors in IE.

Comment: I had javascript which if the user did not select an option in the dropdown an error would come up. I cannot do this anymore because if a user selects 'no' the boxes are hidden but still register as a value not being selected. Is there a way around this? the code for the script was http://pastebin.com/R3fY1Dvq. I only want the error message to pop up if the user selects 'yes' to the radio box but does not fill in the drop down when submit is clicked

Comment: i am not clear what you wanted. can you provide all HTML and javascript?

Comment: I would like an error message to appear if a user does not select an option from the drop down menu. The problem is that when clicked 'no' the dropdown menus are hidden and the error message still appears as the user cannot select an option from drop down menu. Is there a way around this?

Comment: the code is http://pastebin.com/1XgfTuYd. I also have a submit button link to mysql which submits the data. but when i click 'no' there is no value submitted as dropdowns are hidden so an error pops up. is there away around this to ignore hidden dropdowns?

Comment: If you need quick answer, Create one more question by accepting this one. because it answers the query mentioned by you.