# A dropdown validation error occurs if no value is selected on the associated radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two radio buttons: "Yes" and "No". If "Yes" is selected, the user selects what they want from two drop-down menus. If the user selects "No", the form's JavaScript will grey out both drop-down menus.

My jQuery code is shown below. I added:

```
if(!$("#discount").prop("disabled") && $("#colour1, #shade1").val() == 'please select'){
    //alert('Please select');
}
```

but it did not work.

Both radio buttons' `name` attribute is set to `discount`. The drop-down menus' `id` attributes are `#colour1` and `#shade1`.

The first value of each drop down is "please select":

```
 $( function(){
        $("input[name='discount']").click(function() {
            $("#colour1, #shade1")
            .prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');
            if(!$("#discount").prop("disabled") && $("#colour1, #shade1").val() == 'please select'){ //alert('Please select'); }. 
        }).click();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$( function(){
    $("input[name='discount']").click(function() {
        var isDisabled = (this.value == 'No');
        $("#colour1, #shade1").prop("disabled", isDisabled);

        if(!isDisabled){
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#colour1")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select color');
             }
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#shade11")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select shade');
             }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it does work however when i login it comes up straight away 'please select color' and 'please select shade' because the default value is please select. is there any way around this?

Comment: The above code is executed when you click on the radio buttons. How is it getting executed when you login?

Comment: Removed the initial `click` which was triggered on page load so it will executing this logic. It should be fine now. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I am not sure but when I log in i can see behind the validation error box that the radio button is at 'no' but the 2 dropdowns are NOT greyed out until i click 'ok' on both validation error boxes

Comment: yes thats it working now but I would like the error message to come up once the 'submit' button is clicked if 1 or both drop downs are 'please select' value not when the 'yes' radio box is selected.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: I have a submit buttons which sends the info to MySQL. If the submit button is clicked when the radio button is 'yes' and the drop down value is 'please select' I want the validation error to pop up. Currently it pops up when 'yes' radio button Is selected

Comment: Then execute that code which does the validation on submit click.

Comment: my submit button is called submit. Confirm if code should be:  }).click('submit);

Comment: You are mixing 2 different things in it. This question is answered now you should accept this answer and create a new question then it will be clear.

Comment: please view. Please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165182/prevent-form-from-reloading-when-validation-error-occurs-jquery . You are the only person that will be able to answer this with your knowledge thanks

Comment: Use `button` instead of `submit` and then call `$('formSelector').submit()` when retVal is `true`.

Comment: I have added the necessary code here take a look http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/qbawh/3/

Comment: when I use jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/qbawh/3  code if 'no' is selected on radio button and 'yes' in the other with a value of please select it goes onto my redirect page after validation error when submit button is clicked that I set. Is there anyway around this? I have been trying to modify it for days and I have not yet come up with a result! If 'yes' is both radio boxes and value please select in both it does NOT redirect.

Comment: I have fixed it take a look http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/qbawh/4/. I have added an alert for you to show that form will submit after validation is successful.